# How to get string and two integers as an input in the same line

Tags: python

I want my input in this format    `string N M`

where N, M are integer value . I want this input in same line.

I have tried `input().split()` but it doesn't work.

```
alphabets  = input().split()   # what to do next
```

My input format is **(str, int, int)**.

Comment: Could you provide sample input and output? And why you think it isn't working? Because that's working fine for me.

Comment: i want input as string and its indices say N M as int in same line .

Comment: If you are using Python 2 by chance, please use `raw_input`. Because on Python 3, this works perfectly.

Comment: After the `alphabets  = input().split()`,  `alphabets` will be a list of strings containing `['string', 'N', 'M']`. You can access them with indices such as `alphabets[0]`, `alphabets[1]`, etc. (assuming you're using Python 3) Is that what you want to know?

Comment: i am using python 3 .  problem is that  for ex i have a stirng and its index as input in same line . Like  hello 1 3   where  1 and 3 are the index of string hello . bty thnx for reply

Comment: You still haven't said what the problem is. How is the code **not** doing what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I Believe what you are trying to do is, take a string, and two integers as an input on the same line in console:-

```
string, N, M = input().split(" ")

N = int(N)
M = int(M)

print(string, type(string))
print(N, type(N))
print(M, type(M))
```

The above code prompts for input, here the string and the two integers are separated by " " between them, i.e there should be a space between the string and each integers. I also printed out their datatypes so that it becomes a lot more intuitive for you to understand.

**OUTPUT:-**

```
apple 10 5
apple <class 'str'>
10 <class 'int'>
5 <class 'int'>
```

**NOTE:-** There should be whitespace between each inputs, otherwise unwanted results may arise.

**Examples of legal inputs:-**

```
Hesoyam 100 20
AppleBabyCare 34 1215
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take strings and numbers in single line by following the below code.

Try this,

```
>>> alphabets = [int(v) if v.isnumeric() else v for v in input().split()]
hello 1 3
>>> alphabets
['hello', 1, 3]
```

Comment: I think the input consists of three things, not two.

Comment: @martineau OP last comment, cleared the input format as `hello 1 3`.

Comment: That's what I meant.